# PG - Inserting an open-ended TSRANGE

Tags: postgresql

I have the `punctures` table with the `extent` attribute of `tsrange` type and I need to insert a record with an open-ended `extent` with the lower bound as the current time (`now()`).
I tried

```
INSERT INTO punctures(extent)
VALUES(tsrange(now(), ));
```

and variations of that but all generate an error.

How can I define the `tsrange`?

Comment: Have you tied `tsrange(now()::timestamp, 'infinity'::timestamp )` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [in docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRUCT),

> -- Using NULL for either bound causes the range to be unbounded on that side.
> SELECT numrange(NULL, 2.2);

It is possible to pass NULL to constructor function to represent an unbounded range.

```
melkij=> select tsrange(now()::timestamp, null);
             tsrange             
---------------------------------
 ["2023-12-31 17:34:25.176183",)

melkij=> select upper_inf(tsrange(now()::timestamp, 'infinity'));
 upper_inf 
-----------
 f

melkij=> select upper_inf(tsrange(now()::timestamp, null));
 upper_inf 
-----------
 t
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.